# add password protection to a specific directory from .httaccess

Tags: apache-2.4

I dont have good control over the main apache configuration due to cpanel being implemented, I want to add the following config only when a certain directory (or url for that matter) is beeing accessed, additionally I cant directly add the configuration from the .httaccess sitting on that directory, **i need to do it from the httaccesss sitting in the parent directory**.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Any idea how can I achieve that? i tried using the `<if>` directive and dived into the apache docs but I cant get it to really work.

Comment: Why can't you put it in the correct directory?!

Comment: Note that the correct filename is `.htaccess`, only one `t`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because the htaccess used must be the same for the production and staging server, but this access restriction is only for the staging server,  I want to use the production htaccess on both servers and control any different behaviour from outside of any files in source controll (and that htaccess is part of source control).

Comment: In that case you should put it in the virtual host configuration (and of course, stop using cPanel).

Comment: I hate cpanel but my employer uses it and wants it that way, so it's not up to me. 
cpanel does not seem to let me change the virtualhosts since it rewrites them all the time every time someone changes something using cpanel.

Answer (score 2):

> [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way to
>   make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file,
>   containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a
>   particular document directory, and **the directives apply to that
>   directory, and all subdirectories thereof**.

A `.htaccess` in the parent directory will always affect the parent directory, too. What you are trying to achieve is impossible.